# Search button lost its style on stackexchange.com - Newsletters page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar, stackexchange.com

The search button in the top bar was lost its style on the [stackexchange.com -> Newsletters](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters) page. The search button style is fine on the other pages.

GIF for the same:

[image: Newsletters tab]

When an inspect the element, the following style was overridden in the `.top-bar .searchbar .btn-topbar-primary` CSS class, that caused the styling issue:

```
background-color: #0095ff;
padding: 0 12px;
```

**Configurations:**

Mozilla Firefox: 59.0b10 (64-bit)
Google Chrome: Version 64.0.3282.167 (Official Build) (64-bit)
OS: Windows 7
Zoom: 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been fixed recently.

The CSS class is fine now, so the search button for Newsletter is displaying correctly.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Issue has been fixed]